# Python - values of a list within a dict as multiple columns in a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have nested dicts that have an inner list as a value I'm trying to extrapolate to a csv file under multiple column names. The dict looks like this:

```
{'signal': {'chest': {'ACC': array([[ 0.95539999, -0.222     , -0.55799997],
       [ 0.92579997, -0.2216    , -0.55379999],
       [ 0.90820003, -0.21960002, -0.53920001],
       ...,
       [ 0.87179995, -0.12379998, -0.30419999],
       [ 0.87300003, -0.12339997, -0.30260003],
       [ 0.87020004, -0.12199998, -0.30220002]]), 'ECG': array([[ 0.02142334],
       [ 0.02032471],
       [ 0.01652527],
       ...,
```

I have written code to flatten the dict so that each heading is: signal_chest_ACC, signal_chest_ECG, etc. Albeit ugly.

And I have attempted to process the values of each list such that they will appear under each column. However, it outputs all the values in a single column and not under the appropriate keys. How do I access each index of the array and output them as an individual row of the csv file such that each key(column header) has the appropriate list of values under?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys
import numpy
import cPickle
import pandas as pd
import csv
import itertools

#numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
with (open('S2.pkl', 'rb')) as openfile:
    data = cPickle.load(openfile)

    for key, value in data['signal'].items():
        data['signal_{}'.format(key)] = value
    del data['signal']

    for key, value in data['signal_wrist'].items():
        data['signal_wrist_{}'.format(key)] = value
    del data['signal_wrist']

    for key, value in data['signal_chest'].items():
        data['signal_chest_{}'.format(key)] = value
    del data['signal_chest']

    keys = sorted(data.keys())

    with open('out-testx.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
        w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = "\t")
        w.writerow(keys)
        for key in keys:
            for item in data[key]:
                w.writerow([item])
```

Example ouput:

```
signal_chest_ACC    signal_chest_ECG    ...
[ 0.95539999, -0.222     , -0.55799997]
[ 0.92579997, -0.2216    , -0.55379999]
[ 0.90820003, -0.21960002, -0.53920001]
...
[ 0.02142334]
[ 0.02142334]
[ 0.01652527]
...
```

Desired output:

```
signal_chest_ACC    signal_chest_ECG    ...
[ 0.95539999, -0.222     , -0.55799997]    [ 0.02142334]
[ 0.92579997, -0.2216    , -0.55379999]    [ 0.02142334]
[ 0.90820003, -0.21960002, -0.53920001]    [ 0.01652527]
...
```

Comment: The code you have provided has a clear error in the last line of code, but i don't think that is your issue.

please provide a test input data file, as well as the code you are using...

Comment: @Ouss Fixed the spelling error that I think you may have meant and uploaded the full code I am using. The input data file is huge but it looks like the snippet I've shown above.

Comment: The error at the last line of the code is not a typo... it is more than just a typo...
The values inside the ECG, ACC will not be exported out...
[item] will contain [ACC] and [ECG] literally and not the values you want...

Add some print() functions here and there so that you can find the logical error... or use an IDE to debug the code... or use some tool like Jupyter where you can see the output line by line

Comment: @Ouss I've added an example output to what it currently looks like. Doesn't contain [ACC] and [ECG] literally, but the values I want except all on one column, they don't correspond to the desired headers

Comment: Ok. I see. So the first element of the ACC array in the original file corresponds with the first element of the ECG array and they should be exported in the same row in the final csv file?

Comment: @Ouss Yes. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: i added my answer below....

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood, you want to turn the nested dictionary of differnet ECG and ACC measurements into a flat csv table. the ACC, ECG measurements are ordered list of corresponding value. I started with the code you provided and I made some changes and included comments that explains every step.

Note that you get the same outcome in many different ways but i chose something close to what you started with and i did not try to write efficient code or pythonic code to make sure the answer is clear. What i am trying to say is that there are better and cleaner ways to get the same result but i am trying here to maximise clarity.

```
import cPickle
import csv

def fun():
 #load the pickled file and set the value to data
 with (open('S2.pkl', 'rb')) as openfile:
  data = cPickle.load(openfile)    

 #flatten the nested dictionary (depth 2) 
 for key0, value0 in data.items():
  for key1, value1 in data[key0].items():
   data['{}_{}'.format(key0, key1)] = value1
   for key2, value2 in data['{}_{}'.format(key0, key1)].items():
    data['{}_{}_{}'.format(key0, key1, key2)]=value2
   del data['{}_{}'.format(key0, key1)]
  del data[key0]

 #extract the flatten keys (useful for the csv)
 keys = sorted(data.keys())

 #Turn the dictionary into a table
 rows = []
 firstKey = keys[0]
 for index, value in enumerate(data[firstKey]):
  row = []
  for key in keys:
   row.append(data[key][index])
  rows.append(row)

 #Export datRows as csv
 with open('out-testx.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
  w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = "\t", lineterminator="\n")
  w.writerow(keys)
  for row in rows:
   w.writerow(row) 

if __name__=='__main__':
 fun()
```

Running the code (with the data available) results in:

```
signal_chest_ACC    signal_chest_ECG
[0.95539999, -0.222, -0.55799997]   [0.02142334]
[0.92579997, -0.2216, -0.55379999]  [0.02032471]
[0.90820003, -0.21960002, -0.53920001]  [0.02032471]
[0.87179995, -0.12379998, -0.30419999]  [0.02032471]
[0.87300003, -0.12339997, -0.30260003]  [0.02032471]
[0.87020004, -0.12199998, -0.30220002]  [0.01652527]
```

Good luck analysing the data...

Comment: Thanks, although I don't think the keys have exactly matching outputs, as I keep getting an IndexError: string index out of range, on row.append(data[key][index]).

Comment: The code i provided works with the descriptions and data you provided. If the data you provided is not representative of the problem you have at hand then i cannot help you further.

Comment: Please share the data file or a representative portion of it...